# How to match string to an Array to get the value?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array with corresponding value.

```
Array
(
    [0] => BBsma=200
    [1] => SMAperiod=300
    [2] => SMA1=400
    [3] => SMA2=500
    [4] => EMAperiod=300
    [5] => EMA1=24
    [6] => EMA2=8
)
```

Now I want to match a certain string like for example BBsma that should return 200. Any help?

Got the array using these codes.

```
$txt = file_get_contents('INDICATORS.txt');
$rows = explode("\n", $txt);
array_shift($rows);
```

INDICATORS.txt content

```
 BBperiod=100
 BBsma=200
 SMAperiod=300
 SMA1=400
 SMA2=500
 EMAperiod=300
 EMA1=24
 EMA2=8
```

Comment: How is that a PHP array ?

Comment: Can you show the code how you create this array? I think it's better to make a better formatted array.

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over every line of your array and find the value with a regular match.

**Code:**

```
$txt = file_get_contents('INDICATORS.txt');
$rows = explode("\n", $txt);

/*
$rows = [
    "BBsma=200",
    "SMAperiod=300",
    "SMA1=400",
    "SMA2=500",
    "EMAperiod=300",
    "EMA1=24",
    "EMA2=8",
];
*/
foreach ($rows as $k=>$v) {
    if (preg_match("/(BBsma|SMAperiod|EMAperiod)=([0-9]+)/", $v, $matches)) {
        echo "found value " . $matches[2] . " for entry " . $matches[1] . " in line " . $k . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

found value 200 for entry BBsma in line 0

found value 300 for entry SMAperiod in line 1

found value 300 for entry EMAperiod in line 4

Answer (score 0):

After you explode your text to the lines use this code:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($rows);$i++)
{
    $temp=explode("=",$rows[$i]);
    if(sizeof($temp)==2)
    {
        $arr[$temp[0]]=$temp[1];
    }
}
```

> You will have named array in $arr

if you want to cast second part to int, you just change 6-line to this:

```
$arr[$temp[0]]=intval($temp[1]);
```

Comment: if you access $arr["BBperiod"] it will return 200

Answer (score 0):

You can explode by new line as `PHP_EOL` like this

```
$col = "BBsma";
 $val = "";
 foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$str) as $row){
    $cols = explode("=",$row);
    if(trim($cols[0]) == $col){
       $val = $cols[1];
       break;
    }
 }
 echo "Value $col is : $val";
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/956068)

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use the array a few times, it may be easier to read the file into an associative array in the first place...

```
$rows = [];
$file = "INDICATORS.txt";
$data = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ( $data as $item )   {
    $row = explode("=", $item);
    $rows [$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
echo "EMA1 =".$rows['EMA1'];
```

This doesn't do the `array_shift()` but not sure why it's used, but easy to add back in.

This outputs...

```
EMA1 =24
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using array filter answers your question the best. It returns an array of strings with status code 200. If you wanted to have better control later on and sort / search through codes. I would recommend using array_walk to create some sort of multi dimensional array. Either solution will work.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    "BBsma=200",
    "SMAperiod=300",
    "SMA1=400",
    "SMA2=500",
    "EMAperiod=300",
    "EMA1=24",
    "EMA2=8",
];

$filtered = array_filter($arr,"filter");

function filter($element) {
    return strpos($element,"=200");
}
var_dump($filtered); // Returns array with all matching =200 codes: BBSMA=200
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'BBsma=200' (length=9)
```

Should you want to do more I would recommend doing something like this:

```
///////// WALK The array for better control / manipulation

$walked = [];

array_walk($arr, function($item, $key) use (&$walked) {
    list($key,$value) = explode("=", $item);
    $walked[$key] = $value;
});

var_dump($walked);
```

This is going to give you an array with the parameter as the key and status code as it's value. I originally posted array_map but quickly realized array walk was a cleaner solution.

```
array (size=7)
  'BBsma' => string '200' (length=3)
  'SMAperiod' => string '300' (length=3)
  'SMA1' => string '400' (length=3)
  'SMA2' => string '500' (length=3)
  'EMAperiod' => string '300' (length=3)
  'EMA1' => string '24' (length=2)
  'EMA2' => string '8' (length=1)
```

Working with the array becomes a lot easier this way:

```
echo $walked['BBsma']; // 200
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$anything = array("BBsma"=>"200", "SMAperiod"=>"300", "SMA1"=>"400");
echo "the value is " . $anything['BBsma'];
```

This will return 200

Comment: This is not the answer for this question! "_Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that_" [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)